# What are <stable> and <accessor> when doing Scalac -Xprint:typer?

Tags: scala, scalac

I've written a tiny bit of Scala

```
object SquareNumbers extends App {
  val numbers = List(1,2,3,4,5)
  val squares = numbers map (i => i * i)
  println (squares)
}
```

And run it through `scalac` as so:

```
$ scalac -Xprint:typer SquareNumbers.scala
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // SquareNumbers.scala
package <empty> {
  object SquareNumbers extends Object with App {
    def <init>(): SquareNumbers.type = {
      SquareNumbers.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    private[this] val numbers: List[Int] = immutable.this.List.apply[Int](1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    <stable> <accessor> def numbers: List[Int] = SquareNumbers.this.numbers;
    private[this] val squares: List[Int] = SquareNumbers.this.numbers.map[Int, List[Int]](((i: Int) => i.*(i)))(immutable.this.List.canBuildFrom[Int]);
    <stable> <accessor> def squares: List[Int] = SquareNumbers.this.squares;
    scala.this.Predef.println(SquareNumbers.this.squares)
  }
}
```

My question is, what are `<stable>` and `<accessor>` in the output? What are they called (as in, do they have a collective noun), and what do they do?

At a guess, I'd say that  meant they were vals instead of vars, and  mean that it was a callable from outside of the object...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are internal (i.e., not exposed through the new 2.10 reflection API) *flags*. The official compiler [ScalaDoc site](http://www.scala-lang.org/dist/nightly/docs/compiler/scala/tools/package.html) seems to be down, but you can see the Scala source for [details](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/b7c352a57f65458c66c78a368f75aaaa4a08e443/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Flags.scala#L155):

```
final val STABLE   = 1 << 22 // functions that are assumed to be stable
                             // (typically, access methods for valdefs)
                             // or classes that do not contain abstract types.
```

[And](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/b7c352a57f65458c66c78a368f75aaaa4a08e443/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Flags.scala#L159):

```
final val ACCESSOR = 1 << 27 // a value or variable accessor (getter or setter)
```

Later in that file you can find the mapping between identifiers (e.g. `STABLE`) and the printed strings (`<stable>`), lists of which flags are displayed at which phases, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of *ACCESSOR* is pretty obvious, but that of *STABLE* is not.

AFAICT, *STABLE* denotes a getter of an immutable field (i.e., a `val`), or a method parameter, which is similarly immutable within the scope of the method.  I'd guess that this is used to optimize by eliminating reevaluations.